# What is a "Survey-cum-Tutorial"?

Tags: publications

I am seeing the term "Survey-cum-Tutorial" for the first time. What does it mean and how does it differ from a survey or a tutorial paper?

Comment: You might have ended up on the wrong website... :-)

Comment: Most likely how to make a survey guidelines, posted by an English speaker who loves Latin or a Portuguese with love for English terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cum means combined with.  It is a Latin word, but used in English occasionally.  In addition to knowing this definition, I think if you look at the specific example (if there is one in front of you), you should be able to tell what the writer of the phrase meant.  I don't think there is some general meaning (like it is a common phrase) beyond that, so you need to look at the context to see the writer's meaning.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had tried searching google earlier but didn't find a clue

Comment: Good luck.  Glad to contribute answer-cum-task. ;-)